# SQL query to find 3 month data

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How do I find the last three month data from current date in SQL

```
SELECT Category.name 
FROM Category INNER JOIN Transaction 
ON Category.categoryId = Transaction .category_id 
where DATEDIFF(mm,Transaction.date, Now()) <= 3 
GROUP BY Category.name
```

Comment: You posted a question and a piece of code. How are they related?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about nothing.

Comment: dont know thts why i ask...can u told me wht to do...

Comment: someone told me to do that query...so i try but dont work.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, ... ?

Comment: OK, answer below updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. See if it helps.

```
SELECT `Category`.`name` FROM `Category` 
INNER JOIN `Transaction` 
      ON `Category`.`categoryId` = `Transaction`.`category_id` 
WHERE `Transaction`.`date` >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
GROUP BY `Category`.`name`
```